# no function clause matching in Task.async/1

Tags: elixir

I am building a multi of upsert and I am stuck at this part

```
multi =
  Enum.reduce(randoms_info, Multi.new(), fn random_info, multi ->
    Task.async(build_random_multi(multi, random_info, merchant))
  end)
  |> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
  |> build_random_arrangement_multi(store)
```

After running this code the console tells me `(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Task.async/1` what am I doing wrong. Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haved solve this by using this

```
multi =
  Enum.reduce(randoms_info, Multi.new(), Task.async(fn ->
    build_random_multi(&2, &1, merchant)
  end))
  |> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
  |> build_random_arrangement_multi(store)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Task.async/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async/3) spawns a process and returns a `Task.t()`.

It’s hard to tell what are you trying to achieve, without seeing `build_random_multi/3` implementation, but building `Ecto.Multi` (I’m assuming it’s [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto)) is absolutely not time-consuming so I doubt it makes any sense to spawn their composing concurrently.

[`Task.await_many/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await_many/2) would probably be the correct way to await for several tasks, but in your case, it might be directly simplified to the below without any `Task` but with [`Ecto.Multi.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#merge/2).

```rb
multi =
  randoms_info
  |> Enum.reduce(Multi.new(),
    &Multi.merge(&2, build_random_multi(&2, &1, merchant)))
  |> build_random_arrangement_multi(store)
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it returns an error 
```FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Multi.merge/2```

Comment: I have no idea what `build_random_multi/3` returns so it was naïve to expect a working solution here. I showed the correct path.

Comment: it is a function that returns a multi... it contains all the upsert

Comment: But it should be returning the merge of type `(changes() -> t())` as it’s clearly stated in the documentation I linked.

Comment: the error is triggered at the second loop. and I don't have any idea how to solve it. I already tried google'ing it